# Confused because of statement saying a prob dist with lower entropy is a briefer and therefore simpler explanation

Tags: information-theory

The discussion is how to justify picking a simpler model. Mackay here is saying that from an IT perspective it makes sense to pick a simpler model.

From http://andrewgelman.com/2011/12/04/david-mackay-and-occams-razor/

> When you think about it from an information theory / data compression point of view, the Occam story becomes very compelling. P <-> l = log 1/P … Replace “Simpler explanation” by “Briefer explanation”, and it becomes effectively a tautology. “Of course the briefest explanation is the most probable explanation! Because brevity is just log P.” You might enjoy reading about the “bits back” coding method of Geoff Hinton, which accurately embodies this data-compression / Bayesian phenomenon for quite complicated models including latent variables.

But a simpler model is the model that is smoother. So the simpler model will actually have a higher entropy!

edit: I think what is being said is that simpler explanations have higher probability. Because of -log P. But a model (explanation) always involves a probability distribution, I don't find the statement (my first sentence) has any relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'am not sure I understand your question but maybe I do.

You say:

- "simple = high entropy" from some point of view
- "simple = low entropy" from some other point of view

It's just not the entropy of the same thing.

A "simple" model $p_\theta(x)$ has a high entropy as the **entropy of the distribution $p_\theta$**: the average surprisal about $x$ when you will simulate many $x$.

A "simple" model has a low entropy (actually the real name is quantity of information or surprisal here, entropy standing for its average) as the **surprisal of the event "choosing it among other distributions**": the surprisal about $p_\theta$ itself.

A simple distribution is thus:

- something that will simulate observations with average high surprise
- something you are not much surprised to choose

Comment: `A "simple" model has a low entropy (actually the real name is quantity of information or surprisal here, entropy standing for its average) as the surprisal of the event "choosing it among other distributions": the surprisal about pθ itself.` I don't get what you are saying here. Are you talking about the entropy across different probability distributions $p_\theta$?

Comment: There is a distribution on the distributions, like a Bayesian prior. It's the entropy of this prior. More precisely I'm talking about the quantity of information in one sample of this prior.

Comment: I see! Thank you. That makes sense theoretically. I feel like adding though this does not seem like a valuable concept to think about (to me) as I'm pretty sure it is intractable. So although you may talk about doing that (choosing a model with a low entropy in that sense), it seems to me you will never be able to show that is the case.

Comment: I agree very much